# name a file using the time on Windows

Tags: windows, r

I want to save the R output to a specific place, but what I want to do is add the time and day to the file(according to the system time).

```
29-Jul-2010 15.35.txt
```

anyway to do it?

I know about Sys.time and date() but they both contain `:` which windows xp doesn't like.

Comment: Is there the equivalent of C#'s `String.Replace` you could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use format to remove the colons and put in dashes for separtors.

```
format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m%-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

Comment: See ?strptime for the format codes (I can never find these.)

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub(":",".",Sys.time())
```